# Throw exception to PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, propertygrid

I have a `Winforms PropertyGrid`.

When trying to set value in a variable. 
I want to throw an error to `PropertyGrid` as error that appears after putting an **invalid value.**

[image]

There is a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply `throw` an exception in the `set`:

```
private int someProperty;
public int SomeProperty {
    get { return someProperty; }
    set {
        if((value % 3) != 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            "the value must be divisible by 3");
        someProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Produces:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to change the default text "Property value is not valid", so the user does not need to click "Details" to view the error message sent by me?